# Content profile + rules. Problem with action, when user is created a profile then logged in

Tags: rules, users

guys. Got a problem with content_profile and rules modules. By default rules has a

> Redirect to profile creation page, if users have no profile.

It works fine. When a user is registering on the site then logging in, it redirects the registered user to a node/add/profile (Content profile creation page). But when a user that already has a profile node logs in, he's redirecting to mysite.com/node, not on a user page.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want them to go?

> Redirect to profile creation page, *if users have no profile*.

If a user already has a profile node, they won't be directed to create one (as stated in the rule itself) so when the user logs in, he/she should be taken to your default front page (or whatever page he/she was trying to access if access was denied to anonymous users.

---

**EDIT**

If you want users to be directed to the user page if they already have a profile, simply create another rule to do so.  Below is an example of a rule to do this for you:

1. Create a new rule, give it any title you like, for the **Event** select `User has logged in` and click "Save changes"
2. Now click "Add a condition", choose `User has content profile` and click the "Next" button
3. On the settings page for the condition, you may choose what content type to use for your content profile condition.  Choose one (or leave it if using default `Profile`) and click "Save"
4. Now click "Add an action", choose `Page redirect` (under the **System** heading) and click the "Next" button
5. On the settings page for the redirect, in the first textbox for **To:** enter `user`,  click the "Force redirect" checkbox and click "Save" (as seen below):
   [image: Page redirect settings]

Make sure the rule is enabled and your users should be directed to the correct pages.

Comment: For example i have created profile node. I go to the site mysite.com/user and log in, and by default i must be redirected to a users/myname, but im being redirected to a mysite.com/node

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem. With a new install of Drupal with Content Profile and Rules, everything worked as expected.  If you are sure the profile node has been created, perhaps you have a conflicting rule, redirect, module, etc.

Comment: I have logintobogga module on. Maybe it conflicts?

Comment: Possibly, try disabling it and trying again. You might want to look at the issue queue for these modules to see if others have had the same problem. If you have problems with a single module, the issue queue is the best place to go.

Comment: @laxman13: I've noticed that when i logging on via user login block → it redirects me straight to /node. But when im going to a page user/login it redirects me to my profile as intended... :( What can i do with user login block?

Comment: Im not sure why you are seeing that.  I have never heard of that problem.

Comment: @laxman13 so you've got no solutions?

Comment: By the way, i have themed the user-login-block.tpl.php. And it has inside:
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']; ?>?destination=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']); ?>"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="user-login-form">

Maybe the code belove is conflicting?

Comment: Possibly, remove the theming from the login block (use the default template) and try like that and see what happens

Comment: Removed user-login-block.tpl.php - still the same. When im loggin via block it redirects straight to /node

Comment: Did you try disabling the logintoboggan module, you never mentioned that?

Comment: Turning off logintoboggan module doesn't helps :(

Comment: @Heihachi I have made an edit, including a new rule you can use to redirect users that have a profile to their user page.

Comment: i've already tried to create a new rule. But now, when a new user creates account it doesn't redirects to node/add/profile page.
And what is that http://site/user?destination=node
What is destinaion=node for?

Comment: Take a look at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/6.  As for your redirects, it sounds like some sort of conflict dependent on what you have installed.  I don't have time to duplicate your installed modules and configuration to test it out.  Perhaps instead of the modules in use now you could use http://drupal.org/project/login_destination or write your own custom module with hook_form_alter